# Sequelize scope on create

Tags: javascript, typescript, scope, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am quite new to sequelize and trying to use it with `sequelize-typescript`.

I have a user model like this:

```js
@Scopes(() => ({
    authenticated: {
        attributes: {
            exclude: ["password", "email" /* more .. */]
        }
    }
}))
export default class User extends Model<IUser, UserOnCreate> implements IUser {
    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
    declare id: number

    @Unique
    @Column(DataType.STRING(20))
    declare username: string

    @Column(DataType.STRING(64))
    get password(): string { return this.getDataValue("password") }
    set password(p: string) { /* some hashing algorithms */ }

    // more columns...
}
```

Also have a type for authenticated user,

```js
type AuthenticatedUser = Omit<IUser, | "password" | "email" /* more */>
```

And, I am creating a new user with the following code:

```js
await new User(credentials, { raw: true }).save()
```

So is there a easier way to apply `authenticated` scope on create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searchings and browsing of the docs, couldn't find anything.

So, define an array for unwanted keys:

```js
export const authenticableExclude = ["id", "updatedAt", "createdAt", "email"]
```

And define a @AfterCreate hook and set these keys as `undefined`

```js
@AfterCreate
static async editLikeScope(i: User) {
    Object.keys(i.get()).forEach((k) => { 
        if (authenticatedExclude.includes(k)) i.set(k as (keyof IUser), undefined)
    })
}
```

That's it. 
**PS:** The main idea is, @AfterCreate hooks aren't update your model instance, as long as you are not call the `.save()` method. Herewith, attributes can be change and update without affecting the created model.